# Extend object. Is there any way to assign values when the property is available?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, lodash

I have an object

```
        var general = {
            'primary_color': {'value': undefined},
            'logo': {'value': undefined},
        },
```

When i receive data from server i receive something like this

```
        var response = {
            'primary_color': {'value': '#DDD'},
            'logo': null,
        },
```

I wonder if there is any one liner function using will convert my structure as

```
        var result = {
            'primary_color': {'value': '#DDD'},
            'logo': {'value': undefined},
        },
```

Comment: *if there is any one liner function*, **NO**. But why not just parse it from server itself?

Comment: `I wonder if there is any one liner function` since you haven't described the problem yet, try `result=response`, ignore the `general` since you haven't defined how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) by defining which value should be returned, when the current value is `null` or `undefined` by using [`_.isNil()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isNil):

```js
var general = { 'primary_color': {'value': undefined}, 'logo': {'value': undefined} };
var response = { 'primary_color': {'value': '#DDD'}, 'logo': null };

var result = _.mergeWith({}, general, response, function(objValue, srcValue) {
  if(_.isNil(objValue)) {
    return srcValue;
  }
  
  if(_.isNil(srcValue)) {
    return objValue;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome :) [To accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.